# Need assistance in reducing global variable usage in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and decided that diving into a project is the best approach for me to learn. My Chrome extension is a simple one and is finished. However, after doing some research, I discovered that it is written very poorly.

I am trying to clean it up right now and am having a lot of trouble reducing the # of global variables I use. One of the functionalities I implemented is saving the state of the popup menu using the background script. Consider the following two code snippets:

popup.js

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        restore();
    });

    document.getElementById("toggleInput").addEventListener("change", handleEvent);

    function restore(){
        const toggle = document.getElementById("toggleInput");

        chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(page)){
            toggle.checked = page.toggle;
        }

    // handleEvent is a function that sends a message to background.js when it detects a change in 
    // 'document.getElementById("toggleInput")'
```

background.js

```
    window.toggle = "off";

    // Listener & function here that receives message from handlEvent in popup.js and updates 
    // windows.toggle accordingly using simple assignment
```

My main concern is the fact that I'm using window.toggle in my background.js. I read that you're supposed to avoid that and am having trouble applying that new knowledge onto my code and would appreciate some help. I have read about closure but I have no clue how I would apply it to my code. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

PS: I am using window.toggle because I am actually using a background.html as my background page so that I can use export functions in my background.js to avoid a needlessly large background.js file. In that background.html file, I include my background.js script.

Comment: Use chrome.storage.local to store/read `toggle`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Hi I just saw your reply. I'll look into that immediately. Thanks for the reply, really appreciate it.